# How to get probability density function without involving the cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability

I noticed that examples in my textbook always obtains the CDF of the continuous random variable before getting the PDF (derivative of CDF).

For example, the CDF of
$$
Y=aX+b
$$
where $Y$ and $X$ are both random variables is obtained by
$$
F_Y(y)=\Pr(aX+b<y)=\Pr(X<(y-b)/a)
$$ and after consideration of values for $a$, the result is differentiated to get the PDF

$$
f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{|a|}f_X\left(\frac{y-b}{a}\right)
$$

---

If $f_X$ is given, I wish to find $f_Y$ without solving first for the CDF.

$$
f_Y(y)=\Pr(Y=y)=\Pr(X=(y-b)/a)
$$
How do I proceed from here? I am not sure if

$$
\Pr(X=(y-b)/a)=\Pr(X>(y-b)/a)-\Pr(X<(y-b)/a)
$$
If so, then ?
$$
\Longrightarrow=1-F_X((y-b)/a)-F_X((y-b)/a)
$$
I am going nowhere with this.

Comment: If $Y$ is a continuous random variable then $\Pr(Y=y)=0$.  Instead you want the [density with a change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Function_of_random_variables_and_change_of_variables_in_the_probability_density_function)

Comment: @Henry that is new to me, thank you for that, I'll look into it